# Problems with BigInt Library in C++

Tags: c++, bigint

So I'm trying out this bigint library: https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/ on OSX Lion.

I tried making a simple file using the example on their site.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bigint/BigIntegerLibrary.hh>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  BigInteger a;
  int b=5;
  a=b;
  cout<<a;
return 0;
}
```

When I compile this in textmate, the output is:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "BigInteger::BigInteger(int)", referenced from:
      _main in ccl9yNN5.o
  "BigInteger::operator=(BigInteger const&)", referenced from:
      _main in ccl9yNN5.o
  "operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, BigInteger const&)", referenced from:
      _main in ccl9yNN5.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Is there a library that goes along with the header? If so, do you have it installed and linked in your build?

Comment: I'm haven't used any external libraries before so I'm not quite sure what you're talking about...

Comment: This is a screenshot, if it helps. http://cl.ly/2K472I0i2k0h3w2I2d3E

Comment: You need to specify the libraries .lib file in your linker command. Or perhaps you simply failed to compile the source code for the bigint library. It all depends on how you are expected to link to this code. What does the documentation say?

Comment: There aren't any .lib files in the folder.

Comment: There isn't really any kind of documentation and I suppose that the project is dead since the last upload was 2 years ago.

Comment: @cortex Well, but a quick look in the tar file there shows me several .cc files hence it's not a header only class. Which means you'll have to link the generated lib as well and not just the headers..

Comment: @Voo How would I go about doing this in textmate?

Comment: Not the slightest idea I fear - never used that editor (well the OS in general). But basically you build the library which should generate some lib file(s) and then tell your linker to add it (does MacOS use ld and co? In that case you want the `-l` switch; and if the file isn't in its default search path add the path with the `-L` switch)

Answer (score 0):

just in case anyone is still looking for answers to this. I found that you have to dig into the Makefile a little bit and figure out how to manually link the program using the Makefile. What I did is in the bigint folder, I ran "make library" once, then later on, I followed the samples at the very end of the Makefile to link the library files together. Here is my [Makefile](https://raw.github.com/lhr0909/SPOJ/101bedc4e0d38b007b3e41126d311f3621ca48dd/Makefile) trying to solve [an SPOJ problem](http://www.spoj.com/problems/JULKA/):